# Remove One Time Login System in Drupal Forget Password

Tags: php, drupal

How can I remove the one time login system in Drupal? I don't want to use this system when a user clicks "forget password." I want to generate a new password and send it to the user.

Comment: If you do set your site to send passwords through e-mail be sure to register your site at http://www.passwordfail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own module and have it override the standard Drupal solution.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK both options (one time login and new password) are available by default. Check the notification mail text definitions under `admin/user/settings` - they use variables as placeholders, e.g. `!login_url`, `!username`, `!password` and others.

Simply adjust the entries for the 3 mails concerning login (welcome mail, password reset mail and account activation mail) to send only username/passwords instead of login links.

Comment: May be he want to login at every time for visiting site?
In this case sessions settings will help.

Comment: I want to do normal way. Not one time login. I mean, send the mail to user with new password. Thank. It' may help. I will try it.